# Loop for min/max column values using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I best get the min/max column values in a pandas dataframe? Specifically, I'm looking to get the *min/max values for the lengths of the strings,* and take some action based off those values.

I can do this for individual columns but I'd rather loop over all the required columns than complete the tasks as one-offs.

Here is my one off code which works but there has to be a better way, IMO:

```
cols = ['STORE_NO', 'SKU']
    for name in cols:
        inventory_df[name] = inventory_df[name].astype(str)
        long_store = inventory_df.STORE_NO.map(len).max()
        small_store = inventory_df.STORE_NO.map(len).min()
        if long_store == small_store:
            print('Store number values do not appear truncated')
        else:
            print('Some store number values may be truncated')

        long_sku = inventory_df.SKU.map(len).max()
        small_sku = inventory_df.SKU.map(len).min()
        if long_sku == small_sku:
            print('SKU values do not appear truncated')
        else:
            print('Some SKU values may be truncated')
```

Comment: Looks reasonable, you could iterate over all the columns with a `for col in df.columns.values:` or `...in ['JUST', 'SOME', 'SUBSET']:` then using `df[col]` rather than `df.col` access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.columns` on your DataFrame to return a list of all of the columns.  Then you can iterate through this list to accomplish what you have in your code sample.

```
for name in inventory_df.columns:
    long = inventory_df[name].astype(str).map(len).max()
    small = inventory_df[name].astype(str).map(len).min()
    if long == small:
        print('%s values do not appear truncated' % name)
    else:
        print('Some %s values may be truncated' % name)
```

In case you're unfamiliar, the `%s` is string formatting method that let's you print out the string variable stored in `name`.

Comment: Thank you that's a great help!